# supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): okhttp3.Request okhttp3.Authenticator

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp, android-studio-3.0

Static interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): okhttp3.Request okhttp3.Authenticator.lambda$static$0(okhttp3.Route, okhttp3.Response)

Answer (score 25):

Add this in your **build.gradle** of your ***Module:app***

```java
android{
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

It will work

Comment: what is the current `JavaVersion` . are you decreasing the java version or increasing .

Comment: It is better to have this:
`sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17`
`targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17`